# Ubuntu Jupyterhub: 500 POST Spawner failed to start [status=1]

Tags: ubuntu, jupyterhub

I am trying to run *jupyterhub* for multiuser mode:

```
sudo jupyterhub
```

I am able to login successfully with the user I used to install *jupyterhub*. However, when I try to login with other users I get the following message:

> 500: Internal Server Error 
>   Spawner failed to start [status=1]

And in the terminal:

> user@server:~$ sudo jupyterhub
>
> [I 2017-02-18 11:47:53.663 JupyterHub app:733] Loading cookie_secret from /home/user/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
>
> [W 2017-02-18 11:47:53.691 JupyterHub app:372] 
>   Generating CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN. Restarting the Hub will require restarting the proxy.
>   Set CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN env or JupyterHub.proxy_auth_token config to avoid this message.
>
> [W 2017-02-18 11:47:53.695 JupyterHub app:874] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
>
> [W 2017-02-18 11:47:53.695 JupyterHub app:875] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
>
> [I 2017-02-18 11:47:53.695 JupyterHub app:902] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
>
> [I 2017-02-18 11:47:53.714 JupyterHub app:1481] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
>
> [W 2017-02-18 11:47:53.716 JupyterHub app:1201] Running JupyterHub without SSL.  I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else...
>
> [I 2017-02-18 11:47:53.716 JupyterHub app:1203] Starting proxy @ http://*:8000/
>
> 11:47:54.569 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxying http://*:8000 to http://127.0.0.1:8081
>
> 11:47:54.574 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/routes
>
> [I 2017-02-18 11:47:54.597 JupyterHub app:1537] JupyterHub is now running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>
> Last login: Sat Feb 18 00:26:34 CET 2017
>
> Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-62-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
> - Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
> - Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage
>
> 1 package can be updated.
>
> 0 updates are security updates.
>
> [I 2017-02-18 11:48:10.990 JupyterHub spawner:785] Spawning jupyterhub-singleuser '--user="username"' '--cookie-name="jupyter-hub-token-username"' '--base-url="/user/username"' '--hub-host=""' '--hub-prefix="/hub/"' '--hub-api-url="http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/api"' '--ip="127.0.0.1"' --port=52764
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser", line 4, in  **import**('pkg_resources').require('jupyterhub==0.8.0.dev0')   File
>
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3036, in  @_call_aside
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3020, in _call_aside f(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3049, in _initialize_master_working_set working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 654, in _build_master ws.require(**requires**)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 968, in require needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 854, in resolve raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
>
> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jupyterhub==0.8.0.dev0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
>
> [W 2017-02-18 11:48:21.038 JupyterHub web:1545] 500 POST /hub/login?next= (::ffff:10.90.0.4): Spawner failed to start [status=1]
>
> [E 2017-02-18 11:48:21.066 JupyterHub log:99] {
>
> "Content-Length": "36",
>
> "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
>
> "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
>
> "Accept-Language": "en-US",
>
> "Dnt": "1",
>
> "Host": "zeno.lehre.hwr-berlin.de:8000",
>
> "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|1204c4dd|f391c8200e87548242350a9d25406790|1487111102",
>
> "X-Forwarded-Host": "server.com:8000",
>
> "Connection": "close",
>
> "X-Forwarded-For": "::ffff:**.**.*.*",
>
> "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http",
>
> "Accept": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*",
>
> "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
>
> "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
>
> "Referer": "http://server.com:8000/hub/login",
>
> "X-Forwarded-Port": "8000"
>
> }
>
> [E 2017-02-18 11:48:21.066 JupyterHub log:100] 500 POST /hub/login?next= (@::ffff:**.**.*.*) 10283.44ms

I don't know if that would be the source of the problem, however, I have jupyterhub version: 0.7.0. I tried to update it to 0.8.0 using:

```
sudo pip install -U jupyterhub
```

But, I got:

> Requirement already up-to-date: ****

I tried so long to find a solution online; I failed though.

Would someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks :)

Comment: @minrk You have usually ideas for such problems. Would you please help me ?

Comment: did this ever work or is it a fresh install? Do you receive the same error messages if you run: `jupyterhub -f /path/to/jupyterhub_config.py --debug` (you should disable extra logs in your jupyter.conf). Do the folders for the users already exist on the srv where jupyterhub is running? Which spawner are you using?

Answer (score 2):

you might install jupyterhub from source and see this log：

"pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jupyterhub==0.8.0.dev0' distribution was not found and is required by the application"

I met the same problem and... this is caused by installing the binary jupyterhub and donot install packages...
after exec

```
pip3 install -r dev-requiremetns.txt .
```

the log let us to do setup.py by "Running setup.py develop for jupyterhub" and then run `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` and then abort and the log let me to use `pip install .` and then run  `pip3 install .`, and then the jupyterhub run normally.

commands below:

```
cd /path to git code/jupyterhub/
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
pip3 install .
```